# Cleaning up "find" function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to create a function that will return a particular object in an array. I ended up putting a function within the function and not sure if this is clean. Here's the code:

```
const getTeam = (teams, teamId) => {
   if(teamId === 0)
      return teams;

   const findTeam = (team) => {
      return team.teamId === teamId;
   }

   teams.find(findTeam);

}
```

And here's the array of teams

```
[
   {
      id: 123,
      name: "Boston Celtics",
      players: [
         { id: 747, name: "John Doe" },
         { id: 749, name: "John Smith" },
      ]
   },
   {
      id: 234,
      name: "LA Lakers",
      players: [
         { id: 888, name: "James Smith" },
         { id: 823, name: "John Green" },
      ]
   }
]
```

My main concern is having the `findTeam()` function within `getTeam()` function.

UPDATE: 
Something like this? Maybe?

```
const getTeam = (teams, teamId) => {
   if(teamId === 0)
      return teams;

   teams.find((team) => {
      return team.teamId === teamId;
   });

}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter maybe?

Comment: mustnt it be return team.id ?

Comment: @ceejayoz `filter` returns all the matches, `find` returns just the first.

Comment: no need for a named function,an anonymous would do it too

Comment: I'm trying to return the whole team object -- if I received a teamId that is different than 0.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with having a function inside another function. This is a fine use of it.

Comment: But as @Jonasw suggested, most people would use an anonymous function for this. It's even less verbose with arrow functions.

Comment: Something like what I put in the UPDATE in original post?

Comment: the outer function is already `getTeam`.  Why create a second function?  your updated code looks like the cleanest way to go. However, `find` returns the first object as an object, and the `return teams` line returns an array of objects.

Comment: Side note: Make sure you return the result of `teams.find` otherwise you're going to get `undefined` unless `teamId === 0`.

Comment: now your update equals my code, except that ive left away the return and parenthises

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 getTeam=(teams,teamId)=>teamId?teams.find(team=>team.id==teamId):teams;
```

Just short not better. As many others noted, anoymous vs. named functions vs. loops will cause a microsecond war, so its not really worth it.

Comment: this is how I would write it. Although maybe with a couple more spaces and on 2 lines :)

Comment: @georg Yay!nounnecessaryspaces ~ the js parser

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.

```
function getTeam(teams,teamId) {
        return teams.filter((x) => x.id === teamId);
};
```

Comment: find() would be clearer and quicker since it will stop after the first item found

Comment: I see the advantages of both. Filter is a good choice if there could be more than one elements with the same teamId. In my case, find is cleaner because -- technically -- I should not have an element with the same teamId more than once.

Comment: If you use filter, though, you will need to handle the return as an array of teams.